# sitecore custom text field

Tags: sitecore, custom-fields, sitecore8

I'm looking for a custom text field that generates an extra text field when needed. Similar to the way a template adds new text fields.
For storage all values can be saved as one comma separated string (or pipe).

Does anyone know if this exists already? I searched the Sitecore marketplace google but haven't found what I need yet.

edit: If none exists yet I will probably make it myself with this reference: https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx

Comment: The closest in-built field is the [Name Value List field](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/custom-sitecore-field-for-storing-keyvalue-data-with-lookups/), you could inherit from that in a similar way and just store an incremental key, or obviously create your own field type.

Comment: Thanks jammyKam, I already started implementing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do need the labels (which need to be translated) and the name value list field doesn't allow duplicate keys we changed our approach.

this was going to be used to input multiple phone numbers, e-mail addresses etc.
In stead we opted to go with separate templates that would be inserted as child items.